# fstab error on boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, fstab

I want a 2nd hard drive to mount at boot

I have this in /etc/fstab

`UUID=7726e231-4373-451d-8588-930becd772c6  /home/server/common ext4    0       1`

When starting I get an error, did I misconfigure the line?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the top of /etc/fstab. It should have a line like this:
`# Device         Mountpoint      FStype  **Options**         Dump    Pass#`

Your mount line has these:

```
# Device              Mountpoint            FStype  Options    Dump    Pass#
UUID=7726...d772c6    /home/server/common   ext4                0       1
```

Notice the lacking value for the field options, which means that it gets parsed as:

```
# Device              Mountpoint            FStype  Options    Dump    Pass#
UUID=7726...d772c6    /home/server/common   ext4       0       1
```

And options `0` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the correct entry should be as follows:

```
UUID=7726e231-4373-451d-8588-930becd772c6 /home/server/common defaults ext4 0 1
```

Comment: I would be very useful to explain why your answer is correct - what is different, why the change and what it does.

Comment: the options go after the FStype so this is actually wrong.